# Clarification on bash arrays: loaded from output of function vs. loaded from a loop

Tags: arrays, bash

I've seen two different behaviors in bash arrays that I am having trouble understanding the underlying nature of:

The first instance, is whenever I capture multiple lines of output to a variable. I'm able to echo all of that data by echoing the name of the array:

```
[bennett@pc foo]$ foo=`cat filea.c`
[bennett@pc foo]$ echo $foo
asfed asdf asdf asd fasd fas dfs dfsd f sd d ddd
[bennett@pc foo]$ echo "$foo"
asfed
asdf
asdf
asd
fasd
fas
dfs
dfsd
f
sd
d
ddd
```

But when I then load another array with the same data using a for loop, the new array must be iterated over in order to echo all of the output, as echoing the name seems to output only the first element:

```
[bennett@pc foo]$ for i in $foo
> do
> otherarray+=( $i )
> done
[bennett@pc foo]$ echo $otherarray
asfed
[bennett@pc foo]$ for i in ${otherarray[@]}
> do
> echo "$i"
> done
asfed
asdf
asdf
asd
fasd
fas
dfs
dfsd
f
sd
d
ddd
```

What is going on behind the scenes here? Are these two different "types" of arrays?

Comment: Your first example isn't an array, it's simply a string.  Attempting to loop it with `for i in $foo` only works because of 1) variable expansion and 2) none of your entries contain additional whitespace.  If they did, you wouldn't get the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, `foo=$(cat file)`, you now have the foo variable holding a *string*, the contents of the file. The difference between `echo $foo` and `echo "$foo"` is **word splitting** -- see the list of shell expansions: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions

In the second example, you are using word splitting to iterate over the **words** of the contents of the variable, and storing those words into an array.

When you `echo $arrayname` you only get the first element of the array.

When you do not quote the array expansion -- `for i in ${otherarray[@]}` -- again, you are subjecting your data to word splitting.

An example:

```
$ cat file
one  two
three  four

# using the bash builtin for `cat file`
$ foo=$(< file)
$ echo $foo
one two three four
$ echo "$foo"
one  two
three  four
```

now, let's work with an array

```
$ for word in $foo; do
words+=($word)
done
$ echo $words
one

# without quotes
$ printf "%s\n" ${words[@]}
one
two
three
four

# with quotes
$ printf "%s\n" "${words[@]}"
one
two
three
four
```

We can see that each element is a **word** from the file, not a **line**.

Let's use the builtin `mapfile` command

```
$ mapfile -t words < file

# without quotes
$ printf "%s\n" ${words[@]}
one
two
three
four

# with quotes
$ printf "%s\n" "${words[@]}"
one  two
three  four
```

I suspect that's what you want, to store each line of the file as an array element.

Another way to iterate over the **lines** of a file is a while (not for) loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do    # use `IFS=` to avoid trimming whitespace
                               # and `read -r` to avoid messing with backslashes
    array+=("$line")           # use quotes
done < file
```

---

**tl;dr**

- always quote your `"$variables"` except when you know exactly when to leave the quotes off.
- use one of these constructs to iterate over the lines of a file

  ```
  mapfile -t array < file
  while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done < file
  ```